# How to save image with Core Data

Tags: swift, image, core-data, save, binary-data

I am getting the following error **"Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'Data'"** while saving an image as Data type with Core Data. This project functions perfect when the attribute is type String and not Binary Data.

[Core Data Entities:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opTaz.png)

**Add image and Save Change functions inside my ViewModel folder file:**

```
   func addimage(image: Data) {
        let newItem = Item(context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        newItem.id = UUID()
        newItem.image = image
        
        saveChanges()
    }
```

---

```
  func saveChanges() {
        PersistenceController.shared.saveContext() { error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("An error occurred while saving: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            self.fetchItems()
        }}
```

**Content view code with the error message:**

```
struct History: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var image: Data?

init(id: UUID = UUID(),image: Data? = nil)
{   self.id = id
    self.image = image
}}

struct ContentView: View {

 @StateObject private var viewModel = ItemStore()

@State var image: Data?
@State var items = [History]()


var body: some View {

    ScrollView {
        ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in if let image = item.image {
                Image("simpson")}}}


    VStack {
            
            Button {
```

> In the following lines of code I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'Data'"

```
let newHistory = History(image: Image("simpson"))
                    items.append(newHistory)
                    viewModel.addimage(image: Image("simpson"))
                
            } label: {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    .padding()}
            Spacer()
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
viewModel.addimage(image: UIImage(named: "simpson")?.pngData ?? Data())
```